# Python: pip installs sub-packages in root dir

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, pip

I have such structure:

```
setup.py
package
    __init__.py
    sub_package
        ___init__.py
    sub_package2
        __init__.py
```

If I install package via setup.py install, then it works as appreciated (by copying whole package to site-packages dir):

```
site_packages
    package
        sub_package
        sub_package2
```

But if I run pip install package, then pip installs each sub-package as independent package:

```
site-packages
    package
    sub_package
    sub_package2
```

How can I avoid this? I use find_packages() from setuptools to specify packages.

Comment: Can you paste the contents of setup.py?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**NOTE: This answer is not valid anymore, it's only kept for historical reasons, the right answer right now is to use setuptools, more info https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2013-March/020126.html**

---

First of all i will recommend to drop setuptools :

[image]

And use either [distutils](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Distutils) (which is the [standard mechanism to distribute Python packages](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#the-new-standard-distutils)) or [distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) you have also [distutils2](http://bitbucket.org/tarek/distutils2/wiki/Home) but i think  is not ready yet, and for the new standard [here](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html) is a guide line to how to write a setup.py.

For your problem the `find_packages()` don't exist in the **distutils** and you will have to add your package like this:

```
setup(name='package',
      version='0.0dev1',
      description='blalal',
      author='me',
      packages=['package', 'package.sub_package', 'package.sub_package2'])
```

And if you have a lot of package and sub packages you will have to make some code that create the list of packages [here](http://bitbucket.org/django/django/src/tip/setup.py) is an example from Django source.

**I think using distutils can help you with your problem**,and i hope this can help :)

Comment: Thanks. If there will not be way to stay with setuptools I will try distutils.